# Issue with mysql syntax at line 3, not sure what is wrong with code

Tags: mysql, sql

Formatting to display better.

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, CustomerDeliveryAddress, CustomerPhone, CustomerBillingAddress, CustomerCreditCard)
VALUES ('Kristin Foster', '3109 Station St, Austin, TX', '512-443-9548', '3109 Station St, Austin, TX', '1234 5678 9012 3456')
       ('John May', '539 Brentwood Dr, Austin, TX', '512-345-9284', '539 Brentwood Dr, Austin, TX', '2345 6789 0123 4567')
       ('Margie Webb', '3639 Sundown Ln, Elgin, TX', '512-594-6836', '3639 Sundown Ln, Elgin, TX', '3456 7890 1234 5678')
       ('Barry Allen', '3082 Cemetery St, Round Rock, TX', '906-358-1958', '3082 Cemetery St, Round Rock, TX', '4567 8901 2345 6789')
```

Comment: missing `,` after each row of values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Missing comma after each set of values

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, CustomerDeliveryAddress, 
            CustomerPhone, CustomerBillingAddress, CustomerCreditCard) 
VALUES 
('Kristin Foster', '3109 Station St, Austin, TX', 
          '512-443-9548', '3109 Station St, Austin, TX', '1234 5678 9012 3456') , 
('John May', '539 Brentwood Dr, Austin, TX', 
          '512-345-9284', '539 Brentwood Dr, Austin, TX', '2345 6789 0123 4567'),
('Margie Webb', '3639 Sundown Ln, Elgin, TX', 
          '512-594-6836', '3639 Sundown Ln, Elgin, TX', '3456 7890 1234 5678'),
('Barry Allen', '3082 Cemetery St, Round Rock, TX', 
          '906-358-1958', '3082 Cemetery St, Round Rock, TX', '4567 8901 2345 6789')
```